# pod failed to schedule. openstack over kubernates installation

Tags: kubernetes, openstack, kubernetes-helm

I am new to kubernetes and trying to deploy openstack on kubernetes cluster, below is the error I see when I try to deploy openstack. I am following the openstack docs to deploy.

```
kube-system   ingress-error-pages-56b4446784-crl85      0/1       Pending   0          1d
kube-system   ingress-error-pages-56b4446784-m7jrw      0/1       Pending   0          5d
```

I have kubernetes cluster with one master and one node running on debain9. I encounted this error during openstack installation on kubernetes.

Kubectl describe pod shows the event as below:

```
Events:
Type     Reason            Age                 From              Message
----     ------            ----                ----               -------
Warning  FailedScheduling  2m (x7684 over 1d)  default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 1 PodToleratesNodeTaints, 2 MatchNodeSelector.
```

All I see is a failed scheduling, Even the container logs for  kube scheduler shows it failed to schedule a pod, but doesn't say why it failed? I am kind of struck at this step from past few hours trying to debug....

PS: I am running debian9, kube version: v1.9.2+coreos.0, Docker - 17.03.1-ce

Any help appreciated ....

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a toleration on your Pod and don't have nodes with the taints for those tolerations. Would help to post the definition for your Ingress and its corresponding Deployment or DaemonSet.

You would generally taint your node(s) like this:

```
kubectl taint nodes <your-node> key=value:IngressNode
```

Then on your PodSpec something like this:

```
tolerations:
- key: "key"
  operator: "Equal"
  value: "value"
  effect: "IngressNode"
```

It could also be because of missing labels on your node that your Pod needs in the `nodeSelector` field:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    env: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  nodeSelector:
    cpuType: haswell
```

Then on you'd add a label to your node.

```
kubectl label nodes kubernetes-foo-node-1 cpuType=haswell
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @mbuechmann Thanks for correcting the syntax of my question to make it clear.

Rico Thanks for your inputs.

I manged to resolve this issue by adding labels to the nodes. It looks like unless we add labels to the nodes enabling control plain charts can't be deployed.

Use the below command to label node, replace the node name according to your setup
   kubectl label node 5b6s14 openstack-control-plane=enabled
   kubectl label node 5b6s16 openstack-compute-node=enabled

Thanks!

Comment: yes, another issue why it wouldn't get selected it's because of labels. Added a bit more to the answer. Thx.